# save the file in HDFS from a pair RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

Below is the python script which I am using to write in HDFS. RDD is a pair RDD.The script works fine however it creates an entry as tuple in HDFS.Is is possible to remove the tuple and just create comma separated entries in HDFS.

```
    import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'Insufficient arguments'
    sys.exit()

sc = SparkContext()
initialrdd1 = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
finalRDD1 = initialrdd1.map(lambda x:x.split(',')).map(lambda x :(x[1],x[0])).sortByKey()
print finalRDD1.getNumPartitions()
finalRDD1.saveAsTextFile('/export_dir/result3/')
```

file storing in HDFS is in below format

```
(u'Alpha', u'E03')
(u'Beta', u'E02')
(u'Gamma', u'E05')
(u'Delta', u'E09')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not first map the tuple to string and then save it --

```
finalRDD1.map(lambda x: ','.join(str(s) for s in x)).saveAsTextFile('/export_dir/result3/')
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, adding some explanation would help make the answer more useful, especially if it comes up in a search.

Comment: I thought it was minor and self-explanatory suggestion, but sure, point well taken. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
finalRDD1 = initialrdd1.map(lambda x:x.split(',')).map(lambda x :(x[1],x[0])).sortByKey()
```

Understand your code. In your initial RDD, you are mapping each entry to a tuple. **map(lambda x :(x[1],x[0]))**

```
finalRDD1.saveAsTextFile('/export_dir/result3/')
```

After the sortByKey operation, you directly proceed to save the RDD as textfile.

In order to save entries as CSV, you must to specify it explicitly like so -

```
def csv_format(data):
    return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

# Rest of the code ...

finalRDD1.map(csv_format).saveAsTextFile('/export_dir/result3/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The problem with

```
map(lambda x: ','.join(str(s) for s in x)).saveAsTextFile(....)
```

is that it will save  'join' as one string and that will hide the comma and could be a headache if you are planning to use for analysis like loading as pandas df. So you string will look like this

```
[ 'Alpha, E03', 'Beta, E02',....]
```

Simple solution would be to insert another map split before saveAsTextFile()

```
.map(lambda x: x.split(',')).saveAsTextFile(....)
```

So final code will look like this

```
finalRDD1.map(csv_format).map(lambda x: ','.join(str(s) for s in x)).map(lambda x: x.split(',')).saveAsTextFile('/export_dir/result3/')
```

Now your csv will look like this

```
[ 'Alpha', 'E03'] 
['Beta', 'E02']
 .....
 .....
```